# UPDATE in SQL Server 2008 getting '0 rows affected'

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I've changed this query numerous times but still see '0 rows affected. Everything works in `SELECT` statement but fails in the `UPDATE`.

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE tblVisitLog 
SET tblVisitLog.TimeOUT = (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(tblScheduleData.E_Time, 1,2 ) + ':' + SUBSTRING(tblScheduleData.E_Time, 3,2) + ':00.000' AS datetime)
                           FROM tblScheduleData 
                           WHERE tblVisitLog.Encounter_code = tblScheduleData.Encounter_code),
    tblVisitLog.Provider = (SELECT Provider 
                            FROM tblScheduleData s 
                            WHERE tblVisitLog.Encounter_code = s.Encounter_code), 
    tblVisitLog.recStatus = 0,
    tblVisitLog.Printed = N'N'
WHERE 
    tblVisitLog.TimeOUT IS NULL 
    AND tblVisitLog.Provider IS NULL
```

The datatypes are:

```
Encounter_code (int, null)
TimeOUT (datetime, null)
Provider (nvarchar(50), null)
recStatus (smallint, not null)
Printed (nvarchar(50), null)
```

The values that I'm updating are all NULL, the values I'm pulling in from `tblScheduleData.E_Time` are `varchar(4), null` and formatted like '1045'.

Comment: Those subqueries are a little scary. If you get more than 1 row returned that will crash. We can't really help much here because all we can see is an update statement. We don't have any details about either of the tables involved here or the data that may or may not be in them.

Comment: So, I can only do one row at a time? Kind of defeats the purpose of the UPDATE query. I've listed the datatype of the rows involved, would some sample data help?

Comment: Of course you can update more than 1 row at a time. But you are using subqueries for the values. If that subquery returns more than 1 row it will crash because it doesn't know which row you would want to use. And yes some sample data would help. It would also be helpful if you posted the table definitions instead.

Comment: You know you can use a JOIN in an UPDATE statement, right?

Comment: Would the JOINS make the UPDATE run quicker and apply the correct values to the correct rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update statement would be a LOT cleaner using a join here. Something like this.

```
UPDATE vl 
SET TimeOUT = CAST(SUBSTRING(s.E_Time, 1,2 )+ ':' + SUBSTRING(s.E_Time, 3,2) + ':00.000' AS datetime)
    , Provider = s.Provider 
    , recStatus = 0
    , Printed = N'N'
from tblVisitLog vl
join tblScheduleData s on vl.Encounter_code = s.Encounter_code
WHERE vl.TimeOUT Is NULL 
    AND vl.Provider Is Null
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

The message it's pretty clear `'0 rows affected'`
So try do this query and you will see an empty result

```
select * from   tblVisitLog 
WHERE TimeOUT Is NULL AND Provider Is Null
```

First change the criteria